# MongoDB query behaviour with ranges

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am building a realtime app. A Websocket connection is established between clients and server (NodeJS). The clients sends four numeric values. 2 pairs of low and high - with these values the server selects a Range of data.

**No MongoDB used.**

Example:

User sends this data

```
var myObj =  { userid: 10001234, 
               myData: { first: 400, second: 17 },
               first: { low: 300, high: 500 }, 
               second: { low: 10, high: 24 } };
```

Server receiving data does this:

```
serverObj.userid = myObj.userid;
serverObj.myData = myObj.myData;
```

After that the server pushes the serverObj to a collection array at a certain index which it determines via a quicksorting algorithm comparing the myData.first

so we could have an collection array on the server that looks like this if we take a snapshot out of runtime:

```
var collection =  [{ userid: 10001231, 
                     myData: { first: 400, second: 17 } },
                   { userid: 10001232, 
                     myData: { first: 401, second: 31 } },
                   { userid: 10001233, 
                     myData: { first: 402, second: 52 } },
                   { userid: 10001234, 
                     myData: { first: 403, second: 91 } },
                   { userid: 10001235, 
                     myData: { first: 404, second: 800 } },
                   { userid: 10001236, 
                     myData: { first: 405, second: 11 } },
                   { userid: 10001237, 
                     myData: { first: 406, second: 2 } } ];
```

Now pretend the array consists of more than 1000 entries like this.

Next step of the server would be finding the range of values the user requested in the myData.first and myData.second. To achieve this I am determining the index of the myObj.first.low and the index of myObj.first.high and extracts the range between the two indexes from the collection array. 
After that the server resorts the extracted data comparing myData.second. 
Then: determines the index of the myObj.second.low and the index of myObj.second.high and extracts the range between the two indexes from the extracted and resorted array.
The final extracted information contains all values in the range the client has given -> this is then returned to the client.

WOW... well this was not easy to put into words. But I think its easier than just copy & paste all the code ( which would of been a tone of code from my Class ).
What I am doing is really quick, what I didnt think at first because of the complexity. But there is one major issue: I dont save the collection to my memory.

My actual questions now:
Could I reproduce this case to mongodb without losing speed or would i possibly gain speed by doing it? This way data would be saved even if my server crashes.

Please keep in mind: it should be quick. it should be possibly easy.

I am not to familiar with mongoDB but I could also just push the collection array into a MDG collection, lets say, every hour and backup the data in DB on reboot?

What do you think about this case? Is there any smarter algorithm you can think of selecting ranges in this way?

Comment: What is the purpose of storing the data to the database? Will it be used sometime later? Application servers can easily handle what you say the processing of 1000 entries. You just need to implement a good sorting algorithm such as quick sort and then get the range. I don't see a real purpose to use MongoDB here.

Comment: The purpose is to store the data in case the server crashes or needs to be rebooted..... I use quicksort and everything works fine. But What I am asking for are suggestions for a better, safer and maybe faster way to do this without running the risk of losing data